# Git error while merging even though all the changes are pushed with No merge conflict

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, git-merge

I'm seeing some errors regarding git on Jenkins build after pushing my changes. I will try to explain the scenario here:

Here, I'm working on my local branch say - **develop** which was cloned from the **master** branch.

- I made some changes in my develop branch & pushed the changes against the master branch.
- I saw some merge conflicts on the **Stash**.
- Hence, I took the pull of master into my develop branch using

> git pull origin master

- After resolving the conflicts, I pushed the changes but got this issue in my build pipeline. I can't see any conflict issue in my local as well as **Stash**'s UI.
- I can't see any changes left to commit in my local, verified using the command, but it doesn't show any upstaged changes

> git status

**Error message**

```
[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z] ERROR: Checkout failed

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z] hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git merge 7b22e11d41ecfcc22ce4bf5e3f7d9948fc3be363" returned status code 128:

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z] stdout: 

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z] stderr: error: 'merge' is not possible because you have unmerged files.

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z] hint: Fix them up in the work tree,

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z] hint: and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z] hint: appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit,

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z] hint: or use 'git commit -a'.

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z] fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z] 

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2671)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2096)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1996)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1987)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$600(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$3.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:955)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at jenkins.plugins.git.MergeWithGitSCMExtension.decorateRevisionToBuild(MergeWithGitSCMExtension.java:121)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:1164)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1303)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:129)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:154)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.SCMBinder.create(SCMBinder.java:145)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:310)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z]  at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:432)

[2022-03-04T20:02:25.315Z] ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: This looks like a Jenkins error, not a Git problem. I added the [tag:jenkins] tag.